# firebase rules: does user have right to see document

Tags: firebase-authentication, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I am trying to write some rules to allow users to access only the documents they have the rights to.

I have two collections: a "travels" and a "users" collection.

The "travels" collection has several travels (documents) with names "001", "002", "003", ...

The users collection has users (documents) with names "user1@mail.com", "user2@mail.com",...

Inside each user there is an Object (map) called "allowedTravels", in which i keep track of which travels that user can see. Something like this:

```
travels: {
  001: {
    name: 'Nice travel'   
  },
  002: {
    name: 'Amazing Trip'
  }
}


users: {
  user1@email.com: {
    allowedTravels: {
      001: {
        hasPayed: true
      }
    }
  },
  user2@mail.com: {
    allowedTravels: {
      001: {
        hasPayed: false
      },
      002: {
        hasPayed: true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

What i want is to allow users to access the travel documents only if they have access to them, in this case user1 should have access to travel 001, and user2 should have access to travel 001 and 002.

What i want to check is if inside the users document, in the allowedTravels object there is a property with the name of the "travel document". If so: allow, if not: deny

At the moment my rules look like this:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read: if isSignedIn();
    }
  }

  function isSignedIn() {
    return request.auth.uid != null;
  }
}
```

What i have tried was something like this:

```
match /{document} {
  return exists(/users/${request.auth.email}/allowedTravels/{document})
}
```

What would be the correct way to achieve what i am looking for?
I appreciate any help you can give me. thanks!

Comment: I strongly recommend not using email address as the id of a document.  Instead, it's better to use the unique UID assigned to the user by Firebase Authentication.

Comment: ok, i can see why that is a good argument. Thank!!! I will change that! What about a way to authorize the files, any ideas about that?

Comment: any ideas on how to do this?